# JS distinguish between objects and primitives in array

Tags: javascript

I have an update method that should update an item in array:

```
function update(array) {
  return array.map(item => {
    // item or primitive?
  })
}
```

What is the best way (in terms of reliability and performance) to distinguish if it's an array of objects or primitive values?

Comment: You could use `return (value !== Object(value));` to determine if it is primitive. http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/dy791s96/

Comment: Kind of weird to be wanting to do that. Primitives behave a lot like immutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are use `every()` and `typeof` operator

```js
let prim = [1,2,3];
let arrOfObjs = [{a:1},{b:2}];

function isArrayOfObjs(arr){
  return arr.every(x => typeof x === "object");
}

console.log(isArrayOfObjs(prim))   //false
console.log(isArrayOfObjs(arrOfObjs)) //true
```

Comment: Functions aren’t primitives, but they have a `typeof` of `"function"`. Also, `typeof null === "object"`.